# Passing multiple models to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing an asp mvc 5 website. I have 3 models which are appointments, consultations and contacts. now i want to display all the details of these 3 models in a view called userdetails. What i have done so far
Created a view model

```
public class AllServices
{
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    public List<Consultation> Consultations { get; set; }
}
```

Then created the controller action method

```
public ActionResult userdetails()
{ 
    AllServices services = new AllServices();
    services.Appointments = dbcontext.Appointments.ToList();
    services.Consultations = dbcontext.Consultations.ToList();
    services.Contacts = dbcontext.Contacts.ToList();
    return View(services);
}
```

and in view i made

```
@model List<Astrology.ViewModels.AllServices>
....
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @item.Appointments
}
```

but when i run the page iam getting an error like this

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Astrology.ViewModels.AllServices', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Astrology.ViewModels.AllServices]'.

Can someone please help me with it. Iam stuck with this.

Comment: Because you pass a single instance of `AllServices` to a view which expects a collection of `AllServices`. Change the view to `@model Astrology.ViewModels.AllServices`. And its `@foreach(var item in Model.Appointments) { ...`

Comment: what if i want to display all data one model by model in a table with iterations.

Comment: Read the 1st comment!

Comment: I got this output in view when i changed view like u said.. this time no error but the object name itself System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Astrology.Models.Appointment]

Comment: FGS. `@foreach(var item in Model.Appointments) {` is iterating through your collection of `Appointments` - you need to display **properties** of each `Appointment` - `@item.somePropertyOfYourAppointmentModel`

Comment: I have changed view as @model Astrology.ViewModels.AllServices *newline*   "@Model.Appointments"

how can i iterate when im getting only single services object. please tell me how to get all data from that 3 models in my view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151827/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-abhijith).

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you're only passing a single AllServices model when it expects a List of AllServices models. You need to either change the view to expect one model or put the single model into a list.

EDIT (adding code sample)
Change your Controller to something like this:

```
public ActionResult userdetails()
{ 
    List<AllServices> lservices = new List<AllServices>();
    AllServices services = new AllServices();
    services.Appointments = dbcontext.Appointments.ToList();
    services.Consultations = dbcontext.Consultations.ToList();
    services.Contacts = dbcontext.Contacts.ToList();
    lservices.Add(services);
    return View(lservices);
}
```

Comment: can you show me with code? I have already declared view model with list of that properties.

Comment: Edited to show code sample.